# Can't add two caption panels

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I am writing GWT client side.
Here is my code:

```
<g:center type="g:SingleChildWidgetType">
        <g:CaptionPanel captionText="Foreign Data" ui:field="cpForeignData">
            <g:ResizeLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
                <p2:DataGrid ui:field="dataForeign" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
        </g:CaptionPanel>
        <g:CaptionPanel captionText="Merged Data" ui:field="cpMergedData">
            <g:ResizeLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
                <p2:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" ui:field="dataMerged" />
            </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
        </g:CaptionPanel>
    </g:center>
```

I have an error at the beggining of second caption panel:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'g:CaptionPanel'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Does anybody knows the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

**g:center** accepts only one child element. Try to wrap CaptionPanels in one container that matches your needs, for example VerticalPanel:

```
<g:center type="g:SingleChildWidgetType">
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:CaptionPanel captionText="Foreign Data" ui:field="cpForeignData">
            <g:ResizeLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
                <p2:DataGrid ui:field="dataForeign" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
        </g:CaptionPanel>
        <g:CaptionPanel captionText="Merged Data" ui:field="cpMergedData">
            <g:ResizeLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
                <p2:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" ui:field="dataMerged" />
            </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
        </g:CaptionPanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:center>
```